# Croppic/php - uploaded image does not display on localhost

Tags: php

I am using Croppic to allow the user to upload and crop a profile picture. My code is copied from the site so is identical. Yet when i run it on my local computer, the uploaded image does not appear. I get the JSON response of 200 and the path to the uploaded image, but the image does not display. To futher confuse things, if i physically navigate to the folder that the images are uploaded to and attempt to open one, i get a message in windows photo viewer

> "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because you don't have
>   the correct permissions to access the file location"

... despite me owning the folder and having all the correct permissions (windows 7).

Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
<style>
    #profilePicFrame{
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid silver;
        position: relative;
    } 
</style>

<div id = "profilePicFrame">
    <i class = "loader"></i>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cropperOptions = {
            uploadUrl:'/assets/croppic/img_save_to_file.php',
            cropUrl:'/assets/croppic/img_crop_to_file.php',
            imgEyecandy:true,
            imgEyecandyOpacity:0.2
        };

        var cropperHeader = new Croppic('profilePicFrame', cropperOptions);         
    });
</script>
```

Edit:

I've done some more research, and found that if i navigate to the folder that the thumbnail is uploaded to, no thumbnail is displayed, and opening it in windows photo viewer just displays the above permissions error. But if i right click it, i get a prompt saying that i need administrator privileges to change the security settings - click ok - and then see that my windows user is not listed under security tab. Only System and Administrators are. I thought being the only user on this system i was an administrator, at least i have administrator privileges as i could change the settings. If i manually add my windows user to the list, with full access privileges, i am then able to view the image in windows photo viewer.

So why is the image being created without user permissions to view it?

Comment: Any thing glaringly wrong with the code? It is just a windows/localhost issue? I've even tried the croppic-extended package off github and the same thing occurs.

Comment: No. Looks like a trouble with the permissions in the destination folder.

Comment: Well thats what i thought. Even though i edited the img_save_to_file.php to create a dir with permissions of 0777 if it didn't exist (even though windows ignores directory permissions) it still happens. Plus i have given my windows user full ownership of all folders including the upload directory. Is there any thing else i can try to follow up?

Comment: What OS do you use? Show us your web directory location.

Answer (score 1):

Some operating systems can behave a little funny, especially when dealing with apache.

I am assuming as you mentioned using PHP, that you are infact running apache.

When you reference something using *nix or other OS running apache please make sure you reference your files properly.

By telling Apache your **uploadURL** and **cropURL** is at */assets/etc/etc/script.php* this could go back to root especially on a *nix system. You have to be very careful with referencing other scripts - hence not being able to see them maybe?

I am also assuming you used the same file reference in your PHP script will undoubtedly fail as it will try and write the file where Apache does **NOT** have the permissions to do so without heavier modification.